# Subir imagen a servidor desde android studio con WebService

Tags: android

estoy comenzando en android y la verdad aun no puedo reaccionar muy bien ante los errores, estoy trabajando en una aplicacion para capturar imagenes desde la camara y subirlas al servidor todo funciona perfecto pero a la hora de precionar el boton subir solo almacena el nombre de la imagen en mi tabla y no sube la imagen a la carpeta

los archivos php son

upload.php

```
    <?PHP
$ruta = "imagenes/" .basename($_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotoUp']['tmp_name'], $ruta))
       chmod ("uploads/".basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']), 0644);
?>
```

insertImagen.php

```
    <?PHP
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="basededatos";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$imagen=$_POST['imagen'];

$query_search = "insert into imagenes(imagen) values ('".$imagen."')";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($localhost);
?>
```

el metodo android

```
    private void uploadFoto(String imag) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("/upload.php");
        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody foto = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
        mpEntity.addPart("fotoUp", foto);
        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        try {
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 private boolean onInsert(){
        HttpClient httpclient;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        HttpPost httppost;
        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("/insertImagen.php");
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        boolean imagen = nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imagen", nombreImagen.getText().toString().trim() + ".jpg"));

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            return true;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Questions should be asked in English.

Answer (score 1):

Pero el servidor debería hacer ambas operaciones en una sola clase, de tal manera que android se conecte a una sola ruta. Te dejo mi código

Crea un archivo llamado `fileupload.php`

```
<?php

    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error en el archivo: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    } else {
        $target_path = "uploads/" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);  // Ubicación para dejar los archivos subidos
        try {
            /*//Para no sobreescribir
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                echo " El archivo " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " ya existe";
            }else{*/
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
                throw new Exception('El archivo es demaciado grande');
            }
            echo "El archivo " . basename($_FILES['file']['name']) . " ha sido subido correctamente" . "\n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

?>
```

luego creas una carpeta llamada "upload" en el mismo directorio.

Para desarrollar puedes implementar un proyecto php en https://c9.io

y luego apunta tu actividad android al servidor:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://tucuenta.c9users.io/fileUpload.php");
```

y   cambia el parámetro que envías a "file" para que quede como el servidor

```
mpEntity.addPart("file", foto);
```

Answer (score 0):

En `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("/upload.php");` debes poner el url del servidor al que esperas enviar la imagen, debería ser algo así: `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080//upload.php");` espero haberte ayudado